# Validating against duplicate user entries when using sets

Tags: java, arrays, set, duplicates, hashset

I am currently studying Java and have being using normal arrays so far. Next semester we will be using data structures like ArrayList etc, but i decided to read ahead. I have read that for storing data that can not be a duplicate, Sets were the data structure of choice, but in the code below the user can still enter a duplicate entry? Can any body explain the process to me and perhaps a solution to my problem?

```
public class Lotto {

private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 6;

private static final int MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE = 0;

private static final int MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE = 25;

private Set<Integer> userNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

private Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lotto c = new Lotto();
    c.generateRandomNumbers();
    System.out.println("Pick " + INPUT_SIZE + " numbers from "
            + MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + " to " + MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + ".");
    c.readUserNumbers();
    if (c.doUserNumbersMatchRandomNumbers()) {
        System.out.println("You win :) !");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry you failed :( !");
        c.showRandomNumbersToUser();
    }
}

private void generateRandomNumbers() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++) {
        randomNumbers.add(random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE));
    }
}

private void showRandomNumbersToUser() {
    System.out.println("\nRandom numbers where : ");
    for (Integer randomNumber : randomNumbers) {
        System.out.println(randomNumber + "\t");
    }
}

private void readUserNumbers() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputSize = 1;
    while (input.hasNextInt() && inputSize < INPUT_SIZE) {
        int numberChoosen = input.nextInt();
        if (numberChoosen < MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE
                || numberChoosen > MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE) {
            System.out.println("Your number must be in "
                    + MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + " - " + MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE
                    + " range.");
        } else {
            userNumbers.add(numberChoosen);
            inputSize++;
        }
    }
}

private boolean doUserNumbersMatchRandomNumbers() {
    for (Integer userNumber : userNumbers) {
        if (!randomNumbers.contains(userNumber)) {
            return false;
        }
        printMatchingNumber(userNumber);
    }
    return true;
}

private void printMatchingNumber(int num) {
    System.out.println("Your number, " + num + ", has been called.");
}
```

}

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Have you read the javadoc of Set?

Comment: I thought it would throw an exception if I attempted to store a duplicate number. I want to avoid the user entering storing duplicates in the HashSet.

Comment: OK. So you haven't read the javadoc. Read it. That's the best way to know what a class/method does: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29. *If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.* See? No exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets do not prohibit entering a unique value more than once. It is on you to check preconditions, see e.g [Set.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29).

So instead of just calling:

```
userNumbers.add(numberChoosen);
```

try

```
if (!userNumbers.contains(numberChoosen)) {
    userNumbers.add(numberChoosen);
} else {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Set#add(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) returns `true` when the object was added successfully and `false` otherwise. It will not throw an exception, so you need to add a conditional to check whether the operation was successful:

```
if (userNumbers.add(numberChoosen)) {
    System.out.println("Number added successfully");
} else {
    System.out.println("Duplicate number detected");
}
```